# Where HDFS stores files locally by default?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I am running hadoop with default configuration with one-node cluster, and would like to find where HDFS stores files locally.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 31):

You need to look in your **hdfs-default.xml** configuration file for the **dfs.data.dir** setting. The default setting is: **${hadoop.tmp.dir}/dfs/data** and note that the ${hadoop.tmp.dir} is actually in core-default.xml described [here](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/core-default.html).

The configuration options are described [here](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/hdfs-default.html). The description for this setting is:

> Determines where on the local
>   filesystem an DFS data node should
>   store its blocks. If this is a
>   comma-delimited list of directories,
>   then data will be stored in all named
>   directories, typically on different
>   devices. Directories that do not exist
>   are ignored.

Comment: this link is broken :(

Comment: what is the default value of `hadoop.tmp.dir` ?

Comment: From the above core-default.xml link, it shows hadoop.tmpdir = /tmp/hadoop-${user.name}

Answer (score 16):

Seems like for the current version(2.7.1) the dir is

```
/tmp/hadoop-${user.name}/dfs/data
```

Based on `dfs.datanode.data.dir`, `hadoop.tmp.dir` setting from:
http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.1/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/hdfs-default.xml
http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.1/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/core-default.xml

Answer (score 14):

As "more recent answer" and to clarify hadoop version numbers:

If you use **Hadoop 1.2.1** (or something similar), @Binary Nerd's answer is still true.

But if you use **Hadoop 2.1.0-beta** (or something similar), you should read the configuration documentation [here](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/hdfs-default.xml) and the option you want to set is: `dfs.datanode.data.dir`

Answer (score 0):

For hadoop 3.0.0, the hdfs root path is as given by the property `"dfs.datanode.data.dir"`

Answer (score 0):

First find the Hadoop directory present in /usr/lib. There you can find the etc/hadoop directory, where all the configuration files are present.

In that directory you can find the hdfs-site.xml file which contains all the details about HDFS. There you find 2 properties:

dfs.namenode.name.dir – tells where the namenode stores the metadata on the local filesystem.

dfs.datanode.data.dir – tells where the datanode stores the data on the local filesystem

Answer (score -4):

Run this in the `cmd` prompt, and you will get the HDFS location:

```
bin/hadoop fs -ls /
```

Comment: As presented, this command just gives an error.  And you fixed the command, it wouldn't answer the original question at all, -ls isn't going to help in this regard.