# Not able to get rid of famous DataStreamer Exception: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException: error

Tags: java, apache, hadoop, remoteexception

I am running hadoop cluster with Ubuntu host as master-slave and virtual machine running on it as another slave(2 node cluster).

It seems the solution to the problem which is supposed to be resolved at [No data nodes are started](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10097246/no-data-nodes-are-started) is not working for me. I tried both the solutions explained there.

It seems that when i manually equate the namespace ids of the affected datanodes to name node
and start the cluster(solution 2 in the linked post) i still get the same error( DataStreamer Exception).
Next the logs of one of the datanode shows the same Incompatible namespaceIDs error, but the namespace id of data node which is shown in the log is different from that present my tmp/dfs/data/current/version file(which is not changed and is same as that of tmp/dfs/name/current/version)

After many hours of debugging i am still clueless :(.

PS:

- There is no connection problem from my host to slave
- When i start the cluster using start-dfs.sh then datanodes on both the nodes are started which is normall just to clarify.
- This error i am facing when i copy file from local to hdfs.

I performed a simple test after all this

- Deleted the tmp/dfs/data and tmp/dfs/name folder on master
- Deleted    tmp/dfs/data on slave
- format the namenode using hadoop    namenode    -format
- started the cluster using start-dfs. all nodes
- it started normally    on master and datanode is also up on slave
- now    ran    the       copyfromLocal command    and it gave me the
  same    error as below
- But this time there is no namespace mismatch error in any of  datanode logs master or slave

> 14/05/04 04:12:54 WARN hdfs.DFSClient: DataStreamer Exception:
>   org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException: java.io.IOException: File
>   /user/dsingh/mysample could only be replicated to 0 nodes, instead of
>   1     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getAdditionalBlock(FSNamesystem.java:1920)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.addBlock(NameNode.java:783)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:587)   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1432)  at
>   org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1428)  at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1190)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:1426)
>
> at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1113)  at
>   org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Invoker.invoke(RPC.java:229)    at
>   com.sun.proxy.$Proxy1.addBlock(Unknown Source)    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:85)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:62)
>     at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy1.addBlock(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$DFSOutputStream.locateFollowingBlock(DFSClient.java:3720)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$DFSOutputStream.nextBlockOutputStream(DFSClient.java:3580)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$DFSOutputStream.access$2600(DFSClient.java:2783)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.run(DFSClient.java:3023)
>
> 14/05/04 04:12:54 WARN hdfs.DFSClient: Error Recovery for null bad
>   datanode[0] nodes == null 14/05/04 04:12:54 WARN hdfs.DFSClient: Could
>   not get block locations. Source file "/user/dsingh/mysample" -
>   Aborting... put: java.io.IOException: File /user/dsingh/mysample could
>   only be replicated to 0 nodes, instead of 1 14/05/04 04:12:54 ERROR
>   hdfs.DFSClient: Failed to close file /user/dsingh/mysample
>   org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException: java.io.IOException: File
>   /user/dsingh/mysample could only be replicated to 0 nodes, instead of
>   1     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getAdditionalBlock(FSNamesystem.java:1920)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.addBlock(NameNode.java:783)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:587)   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1432)  at
>   org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1428)  at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1190)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:1426)
>
> at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1113)  at
>   org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Invoker.invoke(RPC.java:229)    at
>   com.sun.proxy.$Proxy1.addBlock(Unknown Source)    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:85)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:62)
>     at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy1.addBlock(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$DFSOutputStream.locateFollowingBlock(DFSClient.java:3720)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$DFSOutputStream.nextBlockOutputStream(DFSClient.java:3580)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$DFSOutputStream.access$2600(DFSClient.java:2783)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.run(DFSClient.java:3023)

Any clue will help me .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After working for few hours on this issue. I finally gave up and it is still unresolved in my universe of knowledge.]

But the good thing is that instead of using a virtual box as slave on the same machine I connected another ubuntu machine with my master and every thing worked like charm :)
The problem i guess could be related to limited virtual memory allocation for storage in Virtual machine(It was less than 500Mb) in my case and i have read somewhere that each node in the cluster should have atleast 10 GB of free space to keep HDFS happy.

My take away if possible try the hadoop cluster on 2 separate machines rather than using Virtual machine on same host

Answer (score 0):

After you did -copyFromLocal, seems like the Datanode was up to get request to write the file. However, it wasn't able to allocate the blocks needed for the file. Please check the Datanode log to see exactly what happened. Also, run "hdfs dfsadmin -report" to make sure you have enough space on the Datanode.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same problem. This is all about the lack of space dedicated to hdfs.
I have 10 virtual machine (vmware) nodes which has 3.5 GB average storage for hdfs.I am using hadoop 2.6.

You can decrease the number of replication by going your    "_hadoop_location/etc/hadoop/hdfs-site.xml" (for hadoop 2.6)  configuration file's value of "dfs.replication" property.You can decrease to small number (like 1 or 2) and then try to keep file smaller than your total space.

If it shows the same problem try file size smaller than you used last time or recreate machine with larger disk size.

May be late but it may help others who faced the same problem :) 
Thank you.