# Where hive stores table locally?

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have created a hive table and trying to locate where hive have created an hdfs file for this table locally. The Hive version is **2.3.0**.

I tried this command to retrieve the location of my table

```
hive> describe formatted table_name;
```

I got this as an output(only showing relevant output! **tb2** is the table_name in this case)

```
Location:               hdfs://localhost:54310/user/hive/warehouse/tb2
```

I have no clue how to redirect to hdfs://localhost:54310 **locally**(from terminal). Also the table is not present in hadoop default directory.

Comment: I think that [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2358402/where-hdfs-stores-files-locally-by-default) answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

Try running the below command to view the hive table. In the output you will find a folder by your tablename

hadoop dfs -ls /user/hive/warehouse/tb2

A table in hive is basically a folder in hdfs.

Comment: I got your point. My question is Can't I locate the table locally without **hadoop dfs** means with just the absolute path.