# Where would namenode and datanode be installed if not defined in hdfs-site.xml?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, namenode, hadoop3

My hdfs-site.xml has ONLY the following:

```
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.replication</name>
            <value>1</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

Question.
Where would the NameNode and DataNode be installed?
I am using Hadoop 3.0.3 version on MSFT Surface laptop with Windows 10.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where HDFS stores files locally by default?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2358402/where-hdfs-stores-files-locally-by-default)

Answer (score 1):

In [hdfs-default.xml](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r3.0.3/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/hdfs-default.xml) `dfs.datanode.data.dir` default value is `file://${hadoop.tmp.dir}/dfs/data` and `dfs.namenode.name.dir`  `file://${hadoop.tmp.dir}/dfs/name`

And in [core-default.xml](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r3.0.3/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/core-default.xml) `hadoop.tmp.dir` value is `/tmp/hadoop-${user.name}`

Hence `datanode` located in /tmp/hadoop-${user.name}/dfs/data and `namenode` will be at /tmp/hadoop-${user.name}/dfs/name location.